# solve that $(1 + 1/n)^n$ is more than $2$ and less than $4$ if $n = 2, 3, 4,5 ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Use the binominal series and the relationship between arithmetic and geometric mean.

Comment: So what happens when you employ the two ideas suggested - have you tried the binomial expansion, for example?

Comment: Check this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206271/prove-that-the-sequence-left-1-frac1n-rightn-when-n-to-infty

Answer (score 1):

By the Binomial development,

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=1+\frac nn+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^3}+\cdots\\<1+1+\frac12+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\cdots\\
<1+1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots$$

Note that the second summation is known to be $e$, which is the limit for $n\to\infty$.